# How do I save an NSMutableArray to a SQLite DB?

Tags: cocoa, sqlite, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMUtableArray and I need to save it in an SQLite file.
Is there an API I can leverage for this? 
This is a Mac Desktop application (not for an iPhone)

Comment: Why would you put the iOS tag here, If it's not for iPhone?

Comment: Some concepts cross borders. iOS and Mac OS share a lot of code. NSMutableArray's are an example of data structures that crossed over from Cocoa for OS X. UIKit s for iOS only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Gus Mueller has created an Objective-C wrapper for interfacing with
> SQLite, called FMDB. The latest code for this [can be obtained from
> Github](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). This might be a simpler way to provide your data to SQLite
> than via the raw C API.
>
> Brandon Treb has [written a brief tutorial on the use of FMDB](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/11/04/simple-sqlite-database-interaction-using-fmdb/),
> showing off the framework in action.

Comment: I was looking for a more direct connection to the SQLite DB. I just need to run one SQL Command (INSERT INTO ....) but I'll look into FMDB

Answer (score 9):

Yep, the API is called "Core Data".

You can of course go direct to SQLite with the SQLite library. However, I'd recommend - even for a very simple task - getting your feet wet with Core Data. Once you're over the first steps, it's very easy to use. You can knock up data models in no time, and under the hood all the relational tables will be created for you.

Also, there's tons of great material out there to learn about it. Apple have excellent videos not to mention superb third party tutorials. Just Google "Core Data".

[Here's the programming guide to get you started.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html)

Comment: Core Data sounds like it might be a little much for what I want to do. I just need a simple data entry form which requires 1 table

Comment: I'd still say go with Core Data. By the time you've found and installed the sqlite static lib, created a database, created a table, and written the C API calls to read and write to your one table, you'll be wishing you'd used Core Data. Seriously, you'll never look back!